# Where does Vivado export the address map for the block designs that we can see in Address Editor?

Tags: vivado

I can see the address map for the block design in the address editor of Vivado. I can also see that there is an option to export this as spreadsheet. However, is there a textual output of the address map when we do the "generate output products"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When generate output products function is executed on a block design, the output products usually go into the project srcs directory. This directory is named as project name followed by dot followed by "srcs". A few levels under this directory there will be a folder that has same name as the system builder block design name. This is the folder of interest.

When the system builder block design folder is opened, there will be a file with a .bd extension that has same name as the block design itself. This is the file of interest.

On my machine for this example, the file can be found here for the block design named "design_1":

```
D:\My_Designs\FPGA\Vivado\jtag_to_axi\jtag_to_axi.srcs\sources_1\bd\design_1
```

The .bd file appears to be a JSON file. The JSON is a format that has similar purpose to the XML format but has a simpler form. JSON stores items in a attribute-value pairs similar to the dictionary data structure. It also supports arrays of items.

In the .bd file there will be several sections called "addressing". This will be followed by the AXI master name and eventually, a few levels down the hirarchy, followed by "segments". This is the area of interest in the .bd file. Here is an example:

```
"addressing": {
  "/jtag_axi_0": {
    "address_spaces": {
      "Data": {
        "range": "4G",
        "width": "32",
        "segments": {
          "SEG_axi_bram_ctrl_0_Mem0": {
            "address_block": "/axi_bram_ctrl_0/S_AXI/Mem0",
            "offset": "0xC0000000",
            "range": "8K",
            "is_excluded": "TRUE"
          },
          "SEG_axi_gpio_0_Reg": {
            "address_block": "/axi_gpio_0/S_AXI/Reg",
            "offset": "0x40000000",
            "range": "128"
          },
          "SEG_axi_gpio_1_Reg": {
            "address_block": "/axi_gpio_1/S_AXI/Reg",
            "offset": "0x40010000",
            "range": "128"
          },
          "SEG_axi_gpio_2_Reg": {
            "address_block": "/axi_gpio_2/S_AXI/Reg",
            "offset": "0x40020000",
            "range": "128"
          },
          "SEG_axi_gpio_3_Reg": {
            "address_block": "/axi_gpio_3/S_AXI/Reg",
            "offset": "0x40030000",
            "range": "128"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

The "address_block" followed by "offset" gives the base address of s specific AMBA AXI memory mapped port. The "range" field tells what range has been specified in the block diagram address map and does not necessarily reflect the range actually supported by peripheral itself. The "range" is used to calculate the base address of subsequent peripheral slave buses.

The file is always generated when the generate output products function is executed on the block design. It will have to be parsed to get the required information out. Using Python is one way to do this but not the only way. It will certainly not be easy.

Answer (score 0):

That's the purpose of the .xsa file. You export this from the hardware design (in Vivado) and import it into Vitis to create the software "platform" for your project. Once you build the platform, you'll have an "xparameters.h" file in the system include directory that contains symbols for all of the hardware elements in your design -- start and end addresses, interrupt numbers, etc.

Comment: The xsa file appears to be a binary file, and not an ASCII file. The conversion from xsa to xparameters.h occurs outside Vivado isn't it? In that case is there a way to automate the process using script?

Comment: @gyuunyuu the xsa file is actually just a zip file. You can unzip it (renaming it from .xsa to .zip might help) and see what's inside.